# IdentityServer4 on docker does not work in chrome after upgrading .net core v2.1.13 to v2.1.16

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an application that worked well using .net core v2.1.13.
After upgrading to version v2.1.16, some machines running google chrome are unable to create the .AspNetCore.Correlation.oidc cookie

after the user login he is redirected to https:///signin-oidc where the error is

```
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

the error can be reproduced on a series of computers running the latest version of google chrome. but it works if used in other browsers like firefox, opera, edge, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem starting earlier this month, searched issues on github and threads on stackoverflow with no luck, until I came across this:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/

So it seems Chrome is changing the standard of the "SameSite" property of cookies to enforce it to be set to "Lax", if I understand correctly. By default, when the OIDC middleware middle generates its correlation cookie (and nonce) cookies, it sets the "SameSite" property to "None". So this is what I did in my configuration:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    // Other lines were omitted, only these two are useful to fix your problem

    options.NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax
    options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax

});
```

I don't know that it affects the behavior on other browsers... I tested after that in Chrome, Firefox and Edge with no issues. Someone can correct me on that if it has any side effects that I don't know about.

EDIT: My problem seems to have been resolved by itself, I tried again today in the version without the fix, with the flag clearly turned ON in chrome://flags, and the issue doesn't seem to be happening anymore.

Comment: Hi, can you change same-site "default" to "enabled" mode in chrome://flags?

Comment: If you mean "disabled", yes, I can, and then it works without the fix. But if it's default or enabled I get the error, and I must specify SameSiteMode